# R: How to count all frequencies of values occurring in two columns?

Tags: r, count

So is there a possibility to count the number of occurrences of all values from two columns.
So if I have a table like this:

```
      [From Station ID]   [To Station ID]     [XY]
[1]          85                  28           5287   
[2]          32                  32           4343  
[3]          32                  19           1985
[4]          19                  19           3255 
[5]          19                  55           1111
```

The result should be like this (when selecting the columns"From Station ID" and "To Station ID"):

```
           [Value]             [Count]
[1]          19                  4
[2]          28                  1
[3]          32                  3
[4]          55                  1
[5]          85                  1
```

So it would work similar to the COUNTIF() function in Excel but for two columns and all values in those columns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you mean *columns*, not *rows*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `table` function, after `unlist`ing the first two columns:

```
> table(unlist(mydf[1:2]))

19 28 32 55 85 
 4  1  3  1  1
```

Comment: Thx, for the fast answer! Is there perhaps another possibility without using unlist but rather selecting the two (or more) columns?

Comment: @Deset, I don't quite understand your comment. I've selected the two columns with `1:2` (which represent their position in the `data.frame`). For instance, if your data were in columns 1, 3, and 8, you could do `mydf[c(1, 3, 8)]`. You need to `unlist` those values before tabulating.

Comment: All right,Thank you! I did`t know it would always be necessary to "unlist" the values before making that computation.